# How do I expand a variable inside single quotes?

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I want to run this simple bash script:

```
  curl https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=MyKey -H \\
  'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"longUrl": "$1"}'
```

but bash does not expand the `$1` because of the single quotes after `-d`. Google returns, expectedly, and error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Value",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "resource.longUrl"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Value"
 }
}
```

How do I expand the `$1` inside the single quotes of the json object sent by `-d` in `curl`?

This question does seem to be a duplicate, but I cannot figure out the answer from the other ones. I'm providing the script in the hopes it will be useful for someone else as a contribution.

Comment: You're supposed to use double-quotes instead. Single quotes causes Bash to treat everything within them literally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use double quotes, escaping the ones inside the JSON string:

```
curl https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=MyKey -H \\
  'Content-Type: application/json' -d "{\"longUrl\": \"$1\"}"
```

Comment: Choosing this as the accepted answer because of clarity. I am, however, also upvoting @andlrc's answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) doesn't happen in single quotes, you will need to expand in double quotes:

```
curl https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=MyKey -H \
  'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"longUrl": "'"$1"'"}'
```

String concatenation is used above, below is each shown on a separate line for visibility:

```
'{"longUrl":"'
"$1"
'"}'
```

You should however know that the above will break if `$1` contains a double quote, as the JSON will be invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You can also read the data from a here document, eliminating a layer of quotation marks:

```
curl https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=MyKey -H \\
'Content-Type: application/json' -d@- <<DATA
{"longUrl": "$1"}
DATA
```

Even with this, though, you may still have a problem if `$1` contains double quotes. The safest option is to use something like `jq` to generate the JSON for you.

```
jq -n --arg url "$1" '{longURL: $url}' | curl \
  https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=MyKey \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d@-
```